# Django test with different database user

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I want to keep my unit test database completely separate from other environments including using different user credentials.  This is mostly to prevent anyone from unintentionally running unit tests against the development database and mangling the dev data or wiping it out entirely if the --keepdb option isn't specified.  The code below detects the "test" in the sys args and this seems to work but is very clunky. If I'm missing a better way to do this please advise.

I have separate settings files for each environment so this will only be on the development server where the unit tests are run automatically and won't end up on any production servers.

Environment:
Django 1.11
Python 3.4.x
MariaDB

```
# this works but is clunky
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = { # test db and user
        'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
           'NAME': 'dev_db_test',
           'USER': 'test_user',
           'PASSWORD': 'secretpassword',
           'HOST': 'the-db-host',
           'PORT': '3306',
           'TEST': { # redundant but explicit!
                         'NAME':'dev_db_test',
                    },
           }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
           'NAME': 'dev_db',
           'USER': 'dev_db_user',
           'PASSWORD': 'dev_password',
           'HOST': 'the-db-host',
           'PORT': '3306',
           'TEST': { 
                         'NAME':'dev_db_test', # redundant but explicit!
                    },
           }
    }
```

I'd like to do this but unfortunately Django doesn't look at the TEST credentials

```
# cleaner approach but doesn't work - don't do this!
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'dev_db',
       'USER': 'dev_db_user',
       'PASSWORD': 'dev_password',
       'HOST': 'the-db-host',
       'PORT': '3306',
       'TEST': { 
                 'NAME':'dev_db_test', # Django uses the test db NAME
                 'USER':'test_user_ignored',   # but ignores the USER and PASSWORD
                 'PASSWORD':'ignoredpassword',
                },
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for your situation?

```
import sys

if 'test' in sys.argv:
  NAME = 'dev_db_test'
  USER = 'test_user'
  PASSWORD ='secretpassword'
else:
  NAME = 'dev_db'
  USER = 'dev_db_user'
  PASSWORD ='dev_password'

DATABASES ={ # test db and user
  'default': 
  {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': NAME,
      'USER': USER,
      'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
      'HOST': 'the-db-host',
      'PORT': '3306',
      'TEST': 
      { # redundant but explicit!
        'NAME':'dev_db_test',
      },
  }
}
print(DATABASES)
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm doing now (just defining only the USER and PASSWORD instead of the entire DATABASES dict)

Comment: Awesome! Well I hope my answer was of some help in that process. Good luck on the rest of your app!

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, you don't need to create a separate test database if you want to run unit tests over it. Here is [the documentation link of test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database).

It states that:

```
Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your “real” (production) database. 
Separate, blank databases are created for the tests.
```

You can follow [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests) to write your tests and it will not affect your production or development database.

Comment: That's not what he was asking for.